# How is unit testing better than just testing the entire output of your application as a whole?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I don't understand how an unit test could possibly benefit.
Isn't it sufficient for a tester to test the entire output as a whole rather than doing unit tests?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a ton of questions/answers on this site about unit testing, I'd recommend searching around before you ask a broad question like this.

Comment: But I couldn't find anything as basic as my question ...like why unit test?

Comment: There are moderators who vote to close these discussion type questions in a heartbeat. You've kept the "close nazis" at bay, score one for you. I think it's a great question and is entirely appropriate topic for SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are describing is integration testing.  What integration testing will not tell you is which piece of your massive application is not working correctly when your output is no longer correct.

The advantage to unit testing is that you can write a test for each business assumption or algorithm step that you need your program to perform.  When someone adds or changes code to your application, you immediately know exactly which step, which piece, and maybe even which line of code is broken when a bug is introduced.  The time savings on maintenence for that reason alone makes it worthwhile, but there is an even *bigger* advantage in that regression bugs cannot be introduced (assuming your tests are running automatically when you build your software).  If you fix a bug, and then write a test specifically to catch that bug in the future, there is no way someone could accidentally introduce it again.

The combination of integration testing and unit testing can let you sleep much easier at night, especially when you've checked in a big piece of code that day.

Answer (score 5):

The earlier you catch bugs, the cheaper they are to fix. A bug found during unit testing by the coder is pretty cheap (just fix the darn thing).

A bug found during system or integration testing costs more, since you have to fix it and restart the test cycle.

A bug found by your customer will cost a lot: recoding, retesting, repackaging and so forth. It may also leave a painful boot print on your derriere when you inform management that you didn't catch it during unit testing because you didn't do any, thinking that the system testers would find all the problems :-)

How much money would it cost GM to recall 10,000 cars because the catalytic converter didn't work properly?

Now think of how much it would cost them if they discovered that immediately after those converters were delivered to them, but *before* they were put into those 10,000 cars.

I think you'll find the latter option to be quite a bit cheaper.

That's one reason why test driven development and continuous integration are (sometimes) a good thing - testing is done all the time.

In addition, unit tests don't check that the program works as a whole, just that each little bit performs as expected. That's often quite a *lot* more than higher level tests would check.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience:

1. Integration and functional testing tend to be more indicative of the overall quality of the system, than unit test suit is.
2. High level testing (functional, acceptance) is a QA tool.
3. Unit testing is a **development** tool. Especially in a TDD context, where unit test becomes more of a design implement, rather than that of a quality assurance.
4. As a result of better design, quality of the entire system improves (indirectly).
5. Passing unit test suite is meant to ensure that a single component conforms to the developer's intentions (correctness). Acceptance test is the level that covers validity of the system (i.e. system does what user want it to do).

Summary:

- Unit test is meant as a development tool first, QA tool second.
- Acceptance test is meant as a QA tool.

Answer (score 2):

There is still a need for a certain level of manual testing to be performed but unit testing is used to decrease the number of defects that make it to that stage.  Unit testing tests the smallest parts of the system and if they all work the chances of the application as a whole working correctly are increased significantly.

It also assists when adding new features since regression testing can be performed quickly and automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For a complex enough application, testing the entire output as a whole may not cover enough different possibilities.  For example, any given application has a huge number of different code paths that can be followed depending on input.  In typical testing, there may be many parts of your code that are simply never encountered, because they are only used in certain circumstances, so you can't be sure that any code that isn't run in your test situation, actually works.  Also, errors in one section of code may be masked a majority of the time by something else in another section of code, so you may never discover some errors.

It is better to test each function or class separately.  That way, the test is easier to write, because you are only testing a certain small section of the code.  It's also easier to cover every possible code path when testing, and if you test each small part separately then you can detect errors even when those errors would often be masked by other parts of your code when run in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and try out unit testing first.  I was quite the skeptic myself until I realized just how darned helpful/powerful unit-tests can be.  If you think about it, they aren't really there to add to your workload.  They are there to provide you with peace of mind and allow you to continue extending your application while ensuring that your code is solid.  You get immediate feedback as to when you may have broke something and this is something of extraordinary value.

To your question regarding why to test small sections of code consider this: Suppose your giant app uses a cool XOR encryption scheme that you wrote and eventually product management changes the requirements of how you generate these encrypted strings.  So you say: "Heck, I wrote the the encryption routine so I'll go ahead and make the change.  It'll take me 15 minutes and we'll all go home and have a party."  Well, perhaps you introduced a bug during this process.  But wait!!!  Your handy dandy TestXOREncryption() test method immediately tells you that the expected output did not match the input. Bingo, this is why you broke down your unit tests ahead of time into small "units" to test for because in your big giant application you would not have figured this out nearly as fast.

Also, once you get into the frame of mind of regularly writing unit tests you'll realize that although you pay an upfront cost in the beginning in terms of time, you'll get that back 10 fold later in the development cycle when you can quickly identify areas in your code that have introduced problems.

There is no magic bullet with unit tests because your ability to identify problems is only as good as the tests you write.  It boils down to delivering a better product and relieving yourself of stress and headaches.  =)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with most of the answers. Let's drill down on the topic of speed. Here are some real numbers:

1. **Unit test** results in **1 or 2 minutes** from a
   fresh compile. As true unit tests
   (no interaction with external
   systems like dbs) they can cover a
   lot of logic really fast.
2. **Automated functional test** results in  **1 or 2 hours**. These run on a simplified platform, but sometimes cover multiple systems and the database - which really kills the speed.
3. **Automated integration test** results **once a day**. These exercise the full meal deal, but are so heavy and slow, we can only execute them once a day and it takes a few hours.
4. **Manual regression** results come in after **a few weeks**. We get stuff over to testers a few times a day, but your change isn't realistically regressed for week or two at best.

I want to find out what I broke in 1 or 2 minutes, not a few weeks, not even a few hours. That's where the 10fold ROI on unit tests that people talk about comes from.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question to approach because it questions something of such enormous breadth. Here's my short answer, however:

Test Driven Development (or TDD) seeks to *prove* that every logical unit of an application (or block of code) functions exactly as it should. By making tests as automated as possible for productivity's sake, how could this really be harmful?

By testing every logical piece of code, you can trust the usage of the code up some hierarchy. Say I build an application that relies on a thread-safe stack implementation. Shouldn't the stack be guaranteed to work up at every stage before I build on it?

The key is that if something in the **whole** application breaks, meaning just looking at the total output/outcome, how do you know where it came from? Well, debugging, of course! Which puts you back where you started. TDD allows you to -hopefully- bypass this most painful stage in development.

Answer (score 1):

Testers generally test end to end functionality.  Obviously this is geared for going at user scenarios and has incredible value.

Unit Tests serve a different functionality.  The are the developers way of verifying the components they write work correctly in the absence of other features or in combination with other features.  This offers a range of value including

- Provides **un-ignorable** documentation
- Ability to isolate bugs to specific components
- Verify invariants in the code
- Provide quick, immediate feedback to changes in the code base.

Answer (score 1):

One place to start is regression testing. Once you find a bug, write a small test that demonstrates the bug, fix it, then make sure the test now passes. In future you can run that test before each release to ensure that the bug has not been reintroduced.

Why do that at a unit level instead of a whole-program level? Speed. In good code it's much faster to isolate a small unit and write a tiny test than to drive a complex program through to the bug point. Then when testing a unit test will generally run significantly faster than an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply: Unit tests are easier to write, since you're only testing a single method's functionality. And bugs are easier to fix, since you know exactly what method is broken.

But like the other answerers have pointed out, unit tests aren't the end-all-be-all of testing. They're just the smallest piece of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the single biggest difficulty with software is the sheer number of interacting things, and the most useful technique is to reduce the number of things that have to be considered.

For example, using higher-level languages rather than lower-level improves productivity, because one line is a separate thing, and being able to write a program in fewer lines reduces the number of things.

Procedural programming came about as an attempt to reduce complexity by making it possible to treat a function as a thing.  In order to do that, though, we have to be able to think about what the function does in a coherent manner, and with confidence that we're right.  (Object-oriented programming does a similar thing, on a larger scale.)

There are several ways to do this.  Design-by-contract is a way of exactly specifying what the function does.  Using function parameters rather than global variables to call the function and get results reduces the complexity of the function.

Unit testing is one way to verify that the function does what it is supposed to.  It's usually possible to test all the code in a function, and sometimes all the execution paths.  It is a way to tell if the function works as it should or not.  If the function works, we can think about it as a single thing, rather than as multiple things we have to keep track of.

It serves other purposes.  Unit tests are usually quick to run, and so can catch bugs quickly, when they're easy to fix.  If developers make sure a function passes the tests before being checked in, then the tests are a form of documenting what the function does that is guaranteed correct.  The act of creating the tests forces the test writer to think about what the function should be doing.  After that, whoever wanted the change can look at the tests to see if he or she was properly understood.

By way of contrast, larger tests are not exhaustive, and so can easily miss lots of bugs.  They're bad at localizing bugs.  They are usually performed at fairly long intervals, so they may detect a bug some time after it's made.  They define parts of the total user experience, but provide no basis to reason about any part of the system.  They should not be neglected, but they are not a substitute for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the length of the feedback loop and isolation of the problem to a specific component are key benefits of Unit Tests.

Another way that they are complementary to functional tests is how coverage is tracked in some organizations:

- Unit tests on code coverage
- Functional tests on requirements coverage

Functional tests might miss features that were implemented but are not in the spec.

Being based on the code, Unit tests might miss that a certain feature wasn't implemented, which is where requirements based coverage analysis of Functional testing comes in.

A final point : there are some things that are easier/faster to test at the unit level, especially around error scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing will help you **identify the source** of your bug more clearly and **let you know that you have a problem earlier**.  Both are good to have, but they are different, and unit testing does have benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The software you test is a system. When you are testing it as a whole you are black box testing since you primarily deal with inputs and outputs. [Black box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box_testing) is great when you have no means of getting inside of the system.

But since you usually do, you create a lot of unit tests that actually test your system as a white box. You can slice system open in many ways and organize your tests depending on system internal structure. [White box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_box_testing) provides you with many more ways of testing and analyzing systems. It's clearly complimentary to Black box testing and should not be considered as an alternative or competing methodology.